# XMLHttpRequest with Multiple Headers in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

My current code is

```
Option Explicit


Sub VBA_API_JSON_TEST()

'Declare variables
Dim xml_obj As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

'Create a new Request Object
Set xml_obj = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60


 Dim base_url, param_header1, param_header2 As String
 
    'Define URL Components
    base_url = "https://..."
    
    param_header1 = XMLHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader("key", "1")
    param_header2 = XMLHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader("host", "abc.com")
```

I am getting a variable not defined with XMLHttpRequest error . I have not used this code before and I am unsure what additional code I should be adding, in other examples I have not seen additional code.

```
'Combine all the different components into a single URL
    api_url = base_url + param_header1 + param_header2
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: should be `xml_obj.SetRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "1")`  You have not declared or set any variable named `XMLHttpRequest`  Also I don't think `SetRequestHeader` returns anything, so I'm not clear what you're attempting with that.   If you can provide more info about what you want to do (and maybe the rest of your code) others might have suggestions.

Comment: With this I am simply trying to authenticate my API access. I have an API which I need to send two headers (key and host) with the url. Unfortunately there are very few VBA examples on the web that use code to send two headers with the url. The rare example I found had the XMLHttp.... code but I have not done this before and am trying to keep it all in the one Excel file with VBA.

Comment: URL parameters and headers are two separate things - they aren't related so you need to use either one or the other according to your API docs.

Comment: Unfortunately no docs for use in VBA

Comment: You don't need VBA-specific docs - as long as there's anything telling you what you need to send and here it goes (GET/POST?  In URL or as headers?)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found that putting the code in this order worked to get a 200 response (several hours of looking later!):

```
Dim xml_obj As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set xml_obj = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
base_url = "https://url_endpoint.com"
xml_obj.Open "GET", base_url
xml_obj.SetRequestHeader "key", "1234"
xml_obj.SetRequestHeader "host", "data"
xml_obj.Send
```

Also you should have the Tools->Reference - VBA Project Libraries selected

Microsoft Office 1x.0 Object Library,
Microsoft Excel  1x.0 Object library,
Microsoft Scripting Runtime,
Microsoft XML v6.0 or other versions

They may already be active. Thanks Tim for the xml_obj comment.